# AWS S3 Bucket Policy - Principle Syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Right now I have my policy defined on my S3 bucket but it seems like the principles I have defined are root and when someone under an account who isn't root isn't falling into the allow part of the policy

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::456:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::789:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::101:root"
                ]
            },
```

I tired to specify it as

```
"arn:aws:iam::123:*"
```

but that doesn't work.

I also tried `arn:aws:iam::123:user/sample@yahoo.com` but that too doesn't seem to be correct as it fails with  ***Invalid principal in policy***

Comment: To whom do you wish to grant access -- do you want to grant it to all users in several different AWS accounts?

Answer (score 0):

When granting cross-account permissions, you need both of:

1. A bucket policy on `Bucket-A` in `Account-A` (as above)
2. Permissions on the users in their own account to access `Bucket-A` (which can include wide permissions such as `s3:*`, but that's rarely a good idea)

Not only does the bucket need to permit access, but the users in the originating account must be granted permission to use S3 for the desired actions (eg `s3:GetObject`) on `Bucket-A` (or all buckets).

See: [Bucket Owner Granting Cross-Account Bucket Permissions - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)